# How would i get the total variation demonising for an X-ray image

Tags: total-variation

Total Variation for an X-ray image. using rof model
Is there any function to find total variation.

TV with respect to I by
$$\sum\sqrt{i x^2+i y^2}+\lambda\|i-g\|$$

$I$ is the denoised Image 
$I x$ and $i y$ are gradient.

Comment: [You want to make your xray images demonic?](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/demonising)  Or did autocorrect mangle what you were writing?

Comment: what is "total variation", what is "rof model" , what is "$I$", you only use $i$ in your formula, what is "$g$"? please make sure you actually mathematically define all terms you use.